# php initializing other arrays from the main one

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to initialize 3 arrays(`$tablica1`, `$tablica2`, `$tablica3`) such that `$tablica3` consists of odd numbers and `$tablica2` consists of even ones. Finally, I want to have 3 arrays to echo them on the output later. Should I change my way of dealing with this? (It doesn't work). Thanks for support.

```
$tablica1;
$tablica2;
$tablica3;

for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
  $j = rand(0, 1000);
  $tablica1[$i] = $j; 
  if ($i % 2 == 0) {
    array_push($tablica2, $j);
  } else {
    array_push($tablica3, $j);
  }
}
```

Comment: initialize the three variables with values. In your example with `array()`.  `$tablica1 = array();`. What doesn't work though?

Comment: you missed initialization as @Sbls mentioned. and also you have mistake in code. instead of $i%2 you should use $j%2. see answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
$tablica1 = array();
$tablica2 = array();
$tablica3 = array();

for ($i=0;$i<50;$i++) {
  $j=rand(0,1000);
  $tablica1[$i]=$j; 
  if ($j%2) {
    array_push($tablica3,$j);
  } else {
    array_push($tablica2,$j);
  }
}
```